# Get address of cell in function .Find

Tags: vba, excel

I have code like below, I would like to get address of cell in which value is if value is found. Because if macro find existing value in SomeRange, I would like change value of this cell.

```
Range(SomeRange).Select
    Set a = Selection.Find(What:=Something, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: `MsgBox a.address` unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

You need to guard against not finding anything.

```
dim a as range
Range(SomeRange).Select
on error resume next
Set a = Selection.Find(What:=Something, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
   LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
if not a is nothing then
     debug.print a.address(0, 0)
     a = "changed value"
end if
```

Comment: Could skip the `Select` at once.

Comment: Yes, but then I would feel guilty about not defining the parent worksheet. By using the OP's code for that, I can leave it to the OP to make sure that the correct worksheet is being referenced.

Comment: `.Find` doesn't require the error handling turning off, it will just return nothing if it can't find the value provided.

Comment: @lturner - Thanks for catching that. It also gave me the excuse to revisit and fix the `end fi`.

Comment: For an empty sheet `MsgBox Cells.Find("*").Address` halted into an error fir me. The safeguard seems necessary.

Comment: @user3819867 - I believe that depends upon what the VBE's Tools ► Options ► General ► Error Trapping is set to. But you're right, it should probably be there to catch all scenarios.